# Email a reminder based on the status of a cell Google apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to set a simple reminder email to a technician to remind when a routine service is due. I have a 2d array and code that works, but it only sends 1 email, which is the lowest row.
I'm kinda new to this, but I would like it to run through each row and send a reminder for every overdue.
Any help appreciated.

This is what I have now:

```
    function Email_Reminder() 
    {;

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    statusArray = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    status = "overdue";
    for (i=3;i < statusArray.length;i++){
    if (status == statusArray[i][6]) {
    var customer = statusArray[i][0];
    }
    }
    var email   = "djens12@gmail.com"
    var subject = "Reminder";
    var body    = "This is a reminder that the service is overdue for " +customer+ "";

                      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body,{NoReply : true});
                      }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your `MailApp.sendEmail()` inside your `for` loop

```
function Email_Reminder() 
    {;

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    statusArray = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    status = "overdue";
    var email   = "djens12@gmail.com"
    var subject = "Reminder";

    for (i=3;i < statusArray.length;i++){
      if (status == statusArray[i][6]) {
        var customer = statusArray[i][0];
        var body    = "This is a reminder that the service is overdue for " +customer+ "";
        MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body,{NoReply : true});
      }
    }
  }
```